# Using TFS to output build definitions bin folder on CI build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, add-in, class-library

I just started using TFS not to long ago and I ran into a slight issue. I have a class library project called **EplanInterface.Addin**. This class library project is used as a way to load functionality into a 3rd party program through their API. All of this is working fine but the issue comes into play here:

**The Issue:**

So the problem I am running into is that this Addin library is not referenced by any other projects but still needs to be output to my Drop folder within my TFS build. Typically to load the Addin into the 3rd party program I would copy the debug/release folder to the server and select/load the dll accordingly. My TFS build does not seem to grab the anything from the Addin though?

**App.Config**

Along with that I am using SlowCheetah to try and transform my app.config file resources correctly. Whatever solution provided I need to also figure out how to select a transform when doing the build configuration and output the dlls with the correct build configuration config file.

[image]

**Build Definition**

My build definition is the basic asp.net template they provide which works great for my web api and MVC projects. I guess I am unsure how to force it to also build the addin / output the dll files for my addin to reference?

[image]

**Other Info:**

- TFS Version: 16.122.27102.1
- Addin Project .Net Framework 4.5.2
- Slow Cheetah Version: 3.2.26

Comment: Has your Addin project been successfully built? Or are the dll files not output to the bin folder after the build is successful? Can you share the definition of vs build task and the build log.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I actually went ahead and added an copy task to copy the file. The add in was successfully built. I am unsure if that is the "proper way" to do it but it works for my solution. @HughLin-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add another build task to your pipeline to build the specific addin project and then have it output to the artifacts directory (as the default "Build Solution" task should already be doing).

The other option is to [edit the solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies) file in Visual Studio and include the addin as a project dependency. You may still need to manage the binary output though.